# Computing the proportion of a normally distributed population between specified values of the standard deviation

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Ok I am stuck on the second part of this question.

(a) what percentage of the population is within ± $0.5$ standard deviations of the mean.

(b) what percentage of the population is more than 1 standard deviation above the mean?

For part (a), I got $38.3$% using $P_r(-0.5<z<0.5)$

However, I am stuck on part (b). Is it similar to part (a)?

Comment: yes $P_r(x>\sigma + \mu)$

Comment: If you use tables of the standard normal, you should get $15.87\%$, from $1-0.8413$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empirical rule tells use that $68.2\%$ of the population is within $1$ standard deviation of the mean.  We know that the normal distribution is symmetrical about the mean; thus, we can deduce that $34.1\%$ of the population is between $0$ and $1$ standard deviations above the mean.  Thus, by symmetry, the percentage of the population that is over $1$ standard deviation above the mean is

$50\% - 34.1\% = 15.9\%$

The empirical rule is very useful for reasoning about normal distributions and is something you should commit to memory.  If you need an overview check out [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule).

Comment: @MrOwl glad to help.  Is there something that still isn't clear or is there some other reason you did not accept my answer?